# Hide images on Facebook share

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, share, facebook-sharer

Is there any way to do NOT display any images on FB share dialog?

I checked No Thumbnail in Debug but it doesn't affect on the page. I left meta og:image is empty for the content attribute as well.

I only want to display TEXT ONLY share dialog.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: We will try to find a thumbnail if you don't specify one so I don't think that it is possible

Comment: I think so too but what about "Sharing text-only content as a status message" on the following page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/share#overview ? Thanks!

Comment: Don't add a URL and the user will be able to type in what they want to share.

Comment: Yes, it will provide ability to edit url but I need Share dialog with prepopulated url, title and description. No image. I did some workaround (1x1px transparent image in og:image) but I'd like to use better solution :)

Comment: WizKid, could you tell me is there documented ability to provide FB share  dialog without images? If I leave og:url and og:image tags are empty it captures images for some pages and NOT for others. In facebook debugging it doesn't display captured images and it tells me og:url is not specified. THANK YOU!

Comment: I don't think you can. If you don't specify an og:image we will find one